Pip не хочет скачать ни discord.py ни py-cord
При попытке скачивания через установку модулей pycharm мне пишет ошибку:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
P.S. я не могу скачать через терминал, там свои приколы и python вообще не находит.

На сайтах производителей модулей пишут нечто другое. Команды следует выполнять в соответствующем терминале. Например:
# Linux/macOS
python3 -m pip install -U discord.py

А вот для Windows (я подправил на более умные):
python.exe -m pip install -U pip
pip.exe install -U --compile discord.py

Установить модули в корявой оболочке Pycharm могут только те, кто точно знает что именно нужно делать. Скорее всего, в документации какой-то это есть. Не пытайтесь, оно собственные файлы найти не может, не то что какие-то модули.
Кстати (разработчикам модуля привет), надо быть особо одарённым видимо, что назвать модуль так, как обычно называют скрипты. Проблемы с фантазией.
